# Edit plugin's HTML output with Hooks

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm trying to edit the HTML output of a plugin, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

This is the code

```php
// display the heading
$content .= '<h' . $heading_level . ' class="mbm-book-grid-heading' . ( $l + 1 ) . '">' . esc_html($label) . '</h' . $heading_level .'>';
do_action('mbdb_book_grid_post_heading', $l, $label);
```

What I want to change is the $label, the new code would look like this

```php
$text_label = explode(':', $label);
$text_label = $text_label[1];
$content .= '<h' . $heading_level . ' class="mbm-book-grid-heading' . ( $l + 1 ) . '">' . esc_html($text_label) . '</h' . $heading_level .'>';
```

Now, how can I proceed to that by using Wordpress Actions and Filters? I've never done this before, so I'm a bit confused.

Thanks.

Comment: You can’t. There isn’t a filter on that HTML. There is an action that will let you output something _after_ that code, but nothing to modify the existing code. Not everything is filterable. There might be another method to do what you want, but it’s impossible to say based on this code. I suggest contacting the plugin author.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be possible to do it without the filter, but I found a workaround, I'm just outputting what I need after that code and then I'm hiding the existing one with CSS. Thanks for answering @JacobPeattie

Comment: Edit: I finally found the apply_fiters that I needed! It was below that block of code.